# Render to texture via the framebuffer object

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glsl, 2d-games

I initialize framebuffer. Then, in a cycle I render the scene to a texture, treat its shader and deduce the screen. On my PC everything is OK. (Radeon HD 7870.) On another PC (GeForce FX 5200) the function glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT returns error "8cdd" and render a black screen with a framerate of 0-1 fps.

Source code:

```
#include "main.hpp"

GLuint fbo, fbo_texture, rbo_depth;
GLuint vbo_fbo_vertices;
GLuint program_postproc, attribute_v_coord_postproc, uniform_fbo_texture;
GLuint vs, fs;
Shader shader;

int main(void)
{
    init();

    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &fbo_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture, 0);

    GLenum status;
    if ((status = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT)) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "glCheckFramebufferStatus: error %p", status);
    }
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    GLfloat fbo_vertices[] = { -1, -1, 1, -1,-1,  1, 1,  1 };
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_fbo_vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_fbo_vertices);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(fbo_vertices), fbo_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    shader.load("shaders/post_processing.vert", "shaders/post_processing.frag");

    attribute_v_coord_postproc = glGetAttribLocation(shader.program(), "v_coord");
    if (attribute_v_coord_postproc == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind attribute %s\n", "v_coord");
        return 0;
    }
    uniform_fbo_texture = glGetUniformLocation(shader.program(), "fbo_texture");
    if (uniform_fbo_texture == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind uniform %s\n", "fbo_texture");
        return 0;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_window))
    {
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shader.use();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
        glUniform1i(uniform_fbo_texture, /*GL_TEXTURE*/0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_v_coord_postproc);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_fbo_vertices);
        glVertexAttribPointer(attribute_v_coord_postproc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_v_coord_postproc);
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteRenderbuffersEXT(1, &rbo_depth);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &fbo_texture);
    glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo_fbo_vertices);
    glDeleteProgram(shader.program());
    glfwDestroyWindow(m_window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void callbackError(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

void callbackKey(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void callbackFramebufferSize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    m_width = width; m_height = height;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void init()
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(callbackError);
    if (!glfwInit()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    m_width = 800; m_height = 600;
    m_window = glfwCreateWindow(m_width, m_height, "Framebuffer Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!m_window) { glfwTerminate(); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
    glfwSwapInterval(0);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(m_window, callbackKey);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(m_window, callbackFramebufferSize);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) std::cout << "GLEW Init Error" << std::endl;
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

Result:

http://itmag.es/4KxQ5/

http://itmag.es/H5RD/

Comment: Are you using OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: GeForce FX 5200 is quite old, maybe your `FBO configuration` is not supported on it. Sorry, I don't know enough to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The return value `0x8cdd`<sup>[1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.0/docs/src/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-Core31-Tokens.html#gl_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED)</sup> is the constant `gl_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`.
From the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml)

> GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED is returned if the combination of internal formats of the attached images violates an implementation-dependent set of restrictions.

To find out where the problem lies you can do a couple of things:

**Check the return values**

```
GLenum lastErr:
...
if ((lastErr = glGetError())!= GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "<lastFunctionCalledHere>: error %s", gluErrorString(lastErr));
    return <returnCodeHere>;
}
```

**Check for the presence of the *GL_EXT_framebuffer_object* extension.**

Use `glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, ...)` the get the number of extensions, than use​ `glGetStringi​(GL_EXTENSIONS, i)` with *i* less than the said number.

**Check the implementation constraints**

If none of the above found the cause, try with [glGetXXX](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGet.xhtml) to retrieve some useful value and with [GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) for testing the texture creation.